# How to derive a formula for the period of a simple pendulum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, oscillators, approximations

The following formula is given in our lab manual:
$$ T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{L}{g}} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{4}\sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{9}{64}\sin^4 \frac{\theta}{2}+\cdots \right) $$
for the period of a simple [pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)) with length $L$ under the influence of gravitational acceleration with magnitude $g$. We ignore friction. I understand the solution of Newton's Equation via the small angle approximation $\sin \theta \approxeq \theta$ and why that gives the usual elementary formula $T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$. What I don't understand is how one derives the above formula for higher-order corrections to the period. I think the $\theta$ in the formula is the maximum angle to which the pendulum in question is swinging.

Any insight into the origin or derivation of this formula is appreciated.

Comment: See the section “Legendre polynomial solution for the elliptic integral” at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Arbitrary-amplitude_period

Comment: BTW, there's a *much* nicer formula if you're doing this on a computer, using the AGM, the arithmetic-geometric mean, which converges very quickly.

Comment: The AGM formula is shown at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1139532/207316

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Period of a pendulum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257381/period-of-a-pendulum) See the answer here.  The solution is found in different textbooks, too.  e.g., Engineering Dynamics by Beer & Johnston, , Classical Dynamics by Marion, This derivation is also a problem in Classical Mchanics by Taylor, so OP *might* be looking for that ....

Comment: That answer doesn’t explain how to get the series.

Comment: @BillN I don't spend much time over here in Physics, but that seems pretty far from a direct duplicate. If I was searching for the series formula for the period I don't think that Q and A would be directly helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we take the zero of gravitational potential energy to be at the pivot, then by conservation of energy,

$$\frac{1}{2}m(L\dot{\theta})^2-m g L\cos{\theta}=-m g L\cos{\theta_0}$$

where $\theta_0$ is the maximum angle (where the kinetic energy is zero). This gives the differential equation

$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\sqrt{\frac{2g}{L}(\cos{\theta}-\cos{\theta_0}})$$

which gives the period as four times the time to go from 0 to $\theta_0$:

$$T=4\sqrt\frac{L}{2g}\int_0^{\theta_0}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\cos{\theta}-\cos{\theta_0}}}.$$

Using the trigonometric identity

$$\cos\theta=1-2\sin^2{\frac{\theta}{2}}$$

this becomes

$$T=2\sqrt\frac{L}{g}\int_0^{\theta_0}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\sin^2{\frac{\theta_0}{2}}-\sin^2{\frac{\theta}{2}}}}.$$

With the change of integration variable to $u$ where

$$\sin{u}=\frac{\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}}{\sin{\frac{\theta_0}{2}}}$$

this becomes

$$T=4\sqrt\frac{L}{g}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2{u}}}$$

where

$$k=\sin\frac{\theta_0}{2}.$$

Now use a Taylor expansion and integrate term-by-term to get the result you were given:

$$\begin{align}
T&=4\sqrt\frac{L}{g}\int_0^{\pi/2}du\;\left(1+\frac{1}{2}k^2\sin^2{u}+\frac{3}{8}k^4\sin^4{u}+...\right)\\
&=4\sqrt\frac{L}{g}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{2}k^2\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{3}{8}k^4\frac{3\pi}{16}+...\right) \\
&=2\pi\sqrt\frac{L}{g}\left(1+\frac{1}{4}k^2+\frac{9}{64}k^4+...\right).
\end{align}$$

Comment: I think you'd enjoy *The AGM Simple Pendulum* by Mark B. Villarino.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Exactly the sort of detail I had hoped for.